# How to change the path from custom directive? Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have the following directive which is a button and trying to change the path when clicking on the button but nothing happens.

```
app.directive('searchAgainButton', function ($location) {
    return {
        template: '<button class="searchAgainButton"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i><span> Search Again</span></button>',
        link: function (scop, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function () {
                 $location.path('/index')
            })
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: Did you try using $apply on scope?

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar No, should I put below the $location.path('/index') ?

Comment: `$location` is not stated as a dependency. Should be `app.directive('searchAgainButton', ['$location', function ($location) { // code here }]);`

Comment: Tried element.bind() instead of element.on() ?

Comment: element.bind is deprecated..its better to use on

Comment: You can use $apply after .path() line or create an anonymous function inside $apply.

Answer (score 1):

`element` is not pointing to the the button. Try this

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.directive('searchAgainButton', function ($location) {
        return {
                restrict:"AE",
            template: '<button ng-click="changePath()" class="searchAgainButton"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i><span> Search Again</span></button>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.changePath = function(){
                     $location.path('/index')
                }
             }
         }
    });

//html
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div search-again-button></div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WdVDh/70/)